# Quickly checking whether a branch type exists

Tags: branch, clearcase

With ClearCase, you can check whether a branch type exists by executing:

```
cleartool lstype -kind brtype -invob my_vob
```

... but - this tends to take a lot of time (server load? many branch types?). Is there a faster way to check whether a specific branch type exists or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can try, to see if this is quicker, a [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm)

```
cleartool describe brtype:aBranch@/vobs/avob
# or, for Windows
cleartool describe brtype:aBranch@\avob
```

The idea is: if it fails, the branch does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can get what you want using lstype too. Suppose you're interested in a branch named `my_branch` and your VOB is located at `/path/to/my_vob`:

```
cleartool lstype brtype:my_branch@/path/to/my_vob
```

If you need to know if a global type is instantiated, use:

```
cleartool lstype -local brtype:my_branch@/path/to/my_vob
```

Comment: So, this is for a branch type named "aBranch" and in the VOB named "avob"?